# Convert otf 2 woff with php

Tags: php, type-conversion, woff

for a small type foundry website I´m looking for a way to convert otf files to woff dynamically with php. (The goal would be to use the types with css font-face and not as images!)

Is there a way to do this with php (script should work on shared host), if not are there any Linux command lines tools which can handle this job?

kind regards,

tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I found to do this, is using one of the following two methods.

- Use [fontforge scripting](http://fontforge.github.io/scripting.html) and call it from php
- Use REST font conversion apis [like the one found here](http://everythingfonts.com/fonts/convert/api).

Personally I prefer the later since it works well on any environment and you don't have to mess with compiling fontforge for your host and wrapping it in php.